# What's is the maximum value of sequence in MariaDB

Tags: mariadb

What's is the maximum value of sequence in MariaDB?
Normally we create table to store sequence number.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The maximum of a sequence number or autoincrement column depends on the column (and it's type) which stores the sequence number:

```
TINYINT UNSIGNED   0xFF
SMALLINT UNSIGNED  0xFFFF
MEDIUMINT UNSIGNED 0xFFFFFF
INT UNSIGNED       0xFFFFFFFF
BIGINT UNSIGNED    0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF
```

Comment: Thank you! How to retrieve current sequence number?

Comment: @Janardhan - Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` so we know what to talk about.